# Basic hang man game Python

Tags: python

```
word = input('Enter a word to guess: ')
for n in range(50):
    print('')

Lives = 10
playing = True
lettersGuessed = ''
while playing == True:
    print(str(Lives)+' Lives left')
    if Lives == 0:
        playing = False
        print('You lose')
    else:
        for char in word:
            if char in lettersGuessed:
                print(char, end=' ')
            else:
                print('_', end=' ')
        guess = input('\nEnter a letter to guess: ')
        if guess in word:
            lettersGuessed += guess
        else:
            Lives = Lives-1
```

How would i be able to add a way that the user can win? I've tried comparing the letters guessed with the original word but that didn't work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest implementation*. Add a boolean variable `won` that is initialized to `True`; if any `_` is printed, set it to `False`. It remains `True` only if no `_` was printed:

```
won = True  
for char in word:
    if char in lettersGuessed:
        print(char, end=' ')
    else:
        print('_', end=' ')
        won = False

if won:
    print("Hey, you win!")
```